# Reverse for 'admin-color-product-map-edit' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin1/colorProductMap_edit/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: python, django, view, django-views, django-templates

I'm a new face to Django so please be considerate to if ever my problem is something stupid. So I have been practicing Django, I've run into problems with tegards to NoReverseMatch, I went through answers in stackoverflow but still I couldn't find where I went wrong. Can you help me a bit guys?

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="admin-login")
@user_passes_test(check_role_admin)
def colorProductMap_edit(request, id):
    instance = ColorProductMapping.objects.get(color_p_map_id=id)
    print(instance.color_id)
    form = ColorProductMapForm(instance=instance)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ColorProductMapForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/admin1/colorProductMap')
    else:
        form = ColorProductMapForm(instance=instance)

    return render(request, 'admin1/colorProductMap.html', {'form': form, 'instance': instance})
```

I properly partnered and connected with the following in my urls.py.
**urls.py**

```
path('colorProductMap_edit/<int:id>', views.colorProductMap_edit, name="admin-color-product-map-edit"),
```

**forms.py**

```
class ColorProductMapForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ColorProductMapping
        fields = ['color_id', 'prod_id']
```

**models.py**

```
class ColorProductMapping(models.Model):
    color_p_map_id = models.AutoField("Color & Product Map ID", primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    color_id = models.ForeignKey(Color, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Color ID")
    prod_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Product Id")
```

**colorProductMap.html**

```
{% extends 'admin1/layout/master.html' %}
{% block title %}Color Product Map{% endblock %}
{% block main %}
<h1>
    <center>Color Product Map</center>
</h1>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            {%if colorProductMap_show%}
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-primary">Add
                Color Product Mapping
            </button>
            <div class="modal fade" id="modal-primary">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Add Color Product Mapping</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body mt-2">
                            <form action="{% url 'admin-color-product-map'%}" method="POST"
                                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <table border="1" class="table table-bordered border border-info">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>
                                            {{form.color_id.label_tag}}
                                        </th>
                                        <td>{{form.color_id}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>
                                            {{form.prod_id.label_tag}}
                                        </th>
                                        <td>
                                            {{form.prod_id}}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-right">
                                    <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal -->

            <div class="container-fluid ">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="card mt-2 border border-secondary">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3 class="card-title ">Color Product Map Table</h3>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.card-header -->
                        <div class="card-body">

                            <table class="table table-bordered border border-info">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Color Product Mapping Id</th>
                                    <th>Product ID</th>
                                    <th>Color ID</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody class="justify-content-center">
                                {% for x in colorProductMap_show %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{x.color_p_map_id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{x.prod_id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{x.color_id}}</td>
                                    <td><a href="{% url 'admin-color-product-map-edit' x.color_p_map_id %}"
                                           class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-2"><i
                                            class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                        <a href="{% url 'admin-color-product-map-delete' x.color_p_map_id %}"
                                           class="btn btn-outline-danger mt-2"><i
                                                class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                {% endfor %}

                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                        <!-- /.card-body -->
                        <div class="card-footer clearfix ">
                            <ul class="pagination pagination-sm m-0 justify-content-center">
                                {% if colorProductMap_show.has_previous %}
                                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"
                                                         href="?page={{colorProductMap_show.previous_page_number}}">
                                    Previous </a>
                                </li>
                                {% endif%}
                                {% for x in colorProductMap_show.paginator.page_range %}

                                {% if colorProductMap_show.number == x %}
                                <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{x}}">{{x}}</a></li>
                                {% else%}
                                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{x}}">{{x}}</a></li>
                                {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}

                                {% if colorProductMap_show.has_next %}
                                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"
                                                         href="?page={{colorProductMap_show.next_page_number}}">
                                    Next </a>
                                </li>
                                {% endif %}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card -->
                </div>
            </div>


            {%endif%}
            {% if instance %}
            <form action="{% url 'admin-color-product-map-edit' x.color_p_map_id %}" method="POST"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                 <table border="1" class="table table-bordered border border-info">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>
                                            {{form.color_id.label_tag}}
                                        </th>
                                        <td>{{form.color_id}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>
                                            {{form.prod_id.label_tag}}
                                        </th>
                                        <td>
                                            {{form.prod_id}}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                    <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success w-50"><br>
                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light" data-dismiss="modal">Close
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>

            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

What am I doing wrong? I think I have followed every advice I could find, but yeah it still gives me the error. Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: You have `{% if colorProductMap_show %}` the variable referred here you don't pass into the context from the view, in it you loop over it for x. Now after this if ends you have `{% if instance %}` which you do pass into the context but in it you write `{% url 'admin-color-product-map-edit' x.color_p_map_id %}` Not to mention that the previous loop (which won't even run for this view) has already ended you also don't have any variable x in the context, how would this work?

Comment: Why not `@staff_member_required` by `@user_passes_test(check_role_admin)`?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thanks your comment helped me to find my mistake.

Comment: @WaketZheng I have created my own roles in models so to check the roles I have created some method and cause of that i have used `@user_passes_test(check_role_admin)` instead of `@staff_member_required`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write your form tag as:

```
<form action="{% url 'admin-color-product-map-edit' x.color_p_map_id %}" method="POST"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

After observing your template and view it appears that you are using the same template for multiple views and this is causing confusion. As I note in the comment there is no `x` in the context for this view (In the other one you loop over a variable which doesn't exist in this view to get this). After looking a bit more one notices that by this `{% url 'admin-color-product-map-edit' x.color_p_map_id %}` you want to point to the current url itself. If a forms action is to the same url the best thing to do is **forego** the action attribute completely (If there is no action attribute the request would be to the same url as the page user is in):

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all to guide me, I have found my mistake.

In the html template, as shown below

```
<form action="{% url 'admin-color-product-map-edit' x.color_p_map_id %}" method="POST"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Here I am using **x.color_p_map_id** where **x** is not any iterable object so the error I was getting.

Now I have made a change and used **instance** instead of **x** in above url and now its working fine.

```
<form action="{% url 'admin-color-product-map-edit' instance.color_p_map_id %}" method="POST"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: You **don't need** to set the action attribute it is on the same url the user is on currently. Although this works it will be better to forego it.